# How to cancel 'viewWillAppear' after UIImagePickerController is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, viewwillappear

After a good amount of debugging, I have found that an animation that I had occur in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` was not showing up due to changes that I had occur in `viewWillAppear`.

How can I have the code in `viewWillAppear` not run if the `UIImagePickerController` has just been dismissed? Thanks!

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is called any time the view appears. This includes the first time the view controller is shown itself and any time another view controller shown over it is dismissed. Is the code you have in `viewWillAppear` only meant to run when the view controller is first shown? Or should it be run every time `viewWillAppear` is called except after dismissing the image picker?

Comment: @rmaddy only when the view is first shown. Is it possible to do this?